# Python Syntax error E001

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio

Am very new to python, today i tried with my first code in python in Visual Studio Code. It suddenly throw one syntax error. I don't know what issue am facing. If i copy the same structure code from net, it is working. But the below code throws the Pylinnt E0001 syntax error. Please help me to solve the issue. It throws the issue at line def NodeInsert:.

```
class Node:
    rightNode = None
    leftNode = None
    Value = 0

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.Value = value
        self.rightNode = None
        self.leftNode = None



class Employee:

    empCount = 0

    def __init__(self):
        print("testing")


def NodeInsert:
   empCount=2
```

Comment: it's not indented properly..

Comment: You're missing brackets: `def NodeInsert():`

Comment: @Robert Thanks for your suggestion, i missed brackets with self parameter. Now i changed like this def NodeInsert(self),  its working.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing parenthesis on your `NodeInsert` function declaration.

Therefore, you should change this from:

```
def NodeInsert:
   empCount=2
```

to:

```
def NodeInsert():
   empCount=2
```